# Get a list of GitHub issues by specifying multiple Ids

Tags: github

I simply want do do a GH search in the web-portal like `id in:{1,2,3,7}` but I can't seem to see how. We have a group of issues written down we want to put in a milestone and I don't want to have to manually go to each issue and add to the milestone... but select all these issues from a list of ids and mark them all as belonging to the milestone.

Is it supported somehow?

Comment: Does this help? https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents